# Change div order using CSS when HTML is predefined

Tags: css, xhtml, css-float

Imagine the  following HTML code:

```
   <html>
    ...
    <div id="stuff1">
        barbaz
    </div>

    <div id="stuff2">
        foobar
    </div>
    ...
   </html>
```

Now, suppose I want to make use of CSS so that
`stuff2` appears above `stuff1`. Is there a way to do this
without using `position: absolute` and without changing the HTML
code?

I have tried using `float` like this:

```
#stuff2 { float: left; }
#stuff1 { clear: left; }
```

but it didn't work out. It remained the same as without using
`float`.

Comment: You could do this I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/bCHNh/

Comment: I don't believe you can with floats.  So, no.

Comment: @BillyMoat That really isn't a great method to use.  It is much like using `position: absolute;`

Comment: @derek_duncan - I wasn't saying it was a great method. I don't think that there is a great method to use here. The correct thing to do would be to actually modify the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was successful to get the second element first but not in the next line as you were expecting.

```
#stuff1{display:inline-block;/* or display: inline; */}
#stuff2{float:left;}
```

[**`Working Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/bCHNh/3/)

**or else**

You can also use `transform` CSS3 property

```
#stuff1{
    background-color:red;
    transform: translate(0px, 100px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}
#stuff2{
    background-color:green;
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

[**`Working Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/bCHNh/4/)

And also check this out paul Irish website for performance graph between [translate and positioning](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

If you don't know the height then use [**javascript or jQuery**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15701097/1577396) to calculate the height.

Answer (score 1):

Try below css, may be this we ll be help

```css
#stuff2 { float: left;  margin-top: -40px; }   
#stuff1 { clear: left; margin-top: 30px; }
```